# Recursive bootstrap breadcrumb in angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to use the bootstrap breadcrumb (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/).

I have a component that is used like a directory view in a file system. I want to use the breadcrumb to display the whole path to the current directory.

Here is my folder component template :

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <app-breadcrumb class="breadcrumb" (refresh)="goToGroup($event)" [parent]="currentGroup?.parent" [displayProperty]="'code'" *ngIf="currentGroup !== undefined && currentGroup.parent"></app-breadcrumb>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is my breadcrumb component template :

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a (click)="goTo(parent.uid)">{{parent[displayProperty]}}</a>
</li>
<app-breadcrumb (refresh)="refreshFolder($event)" [parent]="parent.parent" [displayProperty]="displayProperty" *ngIf="parent.parent" class="breadcrumb"></app-breadcrumb>
```

The problem is that css selectors used by bootstrap doesn't work here cause of the nodes added by angular :

[image]

For example, this selector doesn't work :

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
    color: #6c757d;
    content: "/";
}
```

I've tried a few things but can't manage to make it work.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I'm still stuck and I didn't success to fix the issue. Could anyone help me/us? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The + selector is used to select elements that are placed immediately after the last element.

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="nextParent"></div>
```

so you can use :

```
.parent + .nextParent {}
```

In your situation, you should use the selector > which is used to select elements where the parent is the previous element.

```
.breadcrumb > .breadcrumb-item::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  color: #6c757d;
  content: "/";
}
```

or ::before, i dont know exactly whats your needs.

Comment: I tried but it's not working :/.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp : in this case the breadcrumb-item aren't direct children to .breadcrumb cause of the angular added node :/